# Check if a particular string appears in another string

Tags: python, debugging

I am practicing my python coding on this [website](http://codingbat.com/prob/p149391). This is the problem

```
Return True if the given string contains an appearance of "xyz" where the xyz is 
not directly preceeded by a period (.). So "xxyz" counts but "x.xyz" does not. 

xyz_there('abcxyz') → True
xyz_there('abc.xyz') → False
xyz_there('xyz.abc') → True
```

This is my code , for some unknown reason , i dont pass all the testcases. I have problems debugging it

```
def xyz_there(str):

    counter = str.count(".xyz")
    if ( counter > 0 ):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Your code returns True for the string "abc".

Comment: @OmriBarel I linked to the wrong page just now , please have a look at it again

Comment: I was only referring to your code. It returns True for "abc", I'm not sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 4):

It appears the website doesn't allow `import`, so the simplest is probably:

```
'xyz' in test.replace('.xyz', '')
```

Otherwise, you can use a regular expression with a negative look behind assertion:

```
import re

tests = ['abcxyz', 'abc.xyz', 'xyz.abc']
for test in tests:
    res = re.search(r'(?<!\.)xyz', test)
    print test, bool(res)

#abcxyz True
#abc.xyz False
#xyz.abc True
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to see if there's an `xyz` which isn't part of `.xyz` is to count the number of `xyz`s, count the number of `.xyz`s, and then see if there are more of the first than the second.  For example:

```
def xyz_there(s):
    return s.count("xyz") > s.count(".xyz")
```

which passes all the tests on the website.